# RaphaelJS + Chrome: click event not triggering the first time after a toFront() call

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, raphael

If you use the toFront()-method on an element after you dragged it in an svg-image with multiple elements, the click-event of the element does not fire the first time.
If you click on it or drag the same element again, all subsequent click events are fired.
If you change to another element though, again the first click does not fire.
(the same goes for double click, as it relies on the click)

I've created a simple JSFiddle script to reproduce the problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/061h4hv7/1/

You need to open your browser-console to view the output of the script.

If you drag i.e. the red square for the first time the click event is not firing. All subsequent dragging fires the click though (as well as clicking on it).

You can see if the click is not working if the console only logs

```
mouseDown  mouseUp
```

but not

```
mouseDown  mouseUp  click
```

I'm using the Ubuntu-chrome version Version 36.0.1985.125 Ubuntu 14.04 (283153). 
The problem does also occur in Chrome on Windows.
But apparently not in FireFox. I did not yet tested IE (maybe someone can test it?)

Here is the code I'm using to reproduce the problem. Note if you comment out the line
    this.toFront();
everything works just fine.
Unfortunately in my real code the toFront()-call is essential.

It is also important to note, that the drag-method is not the sole trigger for that problem, because I have implemented a different drag-method, where I'm not using a transform, but the problem still persists.

```
var click = function(){
    console.log('click');
};

var dragger = function () {
    console.log('mouseDown');
    this.previousDx = 0;
    this.previousDy = 0;
};

var move = function (dx, dy) {
    console.log('mouseMove');
    var txGroup = dx - this.previousDx;
    var tyGroup = dy - this.previousDy;

    this.translate(txGroup, tyGroup);

    this.previousDx = dx;
    this.previousDy = dy;
};

var up = function () {
    console.log('mouseUp');

    this.toFront();
};

var paper = Raphael(0, 0, "100%", "100%");

var red = paper.rect(10,10,30,30).attr({ 'fill' : 'red' }).drag(move, dragger, up).click(click);
var black = paper.rect(50,10,30,30).attr({ 'fill' : 'black' }).drag(move, dragger, up).click(click);
var blue = paper.rect(90,10,30,30).attr({ 'fill' : 'blue' }).drag(move, dragger, up).click(click);
```

Do you guys know anything to fix the problem? Otherwise I have to implement the click and double click manually by recording the mouseDown and mouseUp calls.

Comment: I think logically it would be better to code it manually and have only one handler, rather than a drag and a click handler. That solution will always get a bit messy I think. Not sure why not just use the mouseup handler ?

Comment: The problem than is, that I also have to manually implement the double click. Meaning I have to save the timestamp of the last mouseup and than look up if it is under the threshold for a double click. This works, but it is not a fine solution.

Comment: I think Raphaels dblclick() method may work fine due to the nature of how you can't really drag and double click at the same time, so that part _may_ not have a problem.